# How to link DroidAR's ModelLoaderAdapters to my project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, location-based

Hi I'm currently trying to build an app by using the location based ar provided by DroidAR but I could not figure how how could I use the Model Loader Adapter provided by DroidAR. The demo they have given is created in Eclipse but I'm using the newest version of Android studio. If anyone has tried out, could you please explain to me what should I do now :( thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have the eclipse project you can import it in android studio, here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#import_projects_to_android_studio)

but if you have its jar file you can add it to your project like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/5197037)